# Ionic app: some native plugin dont work on UWP

Tags: ionic-framework, uwp

I don't know if I ask this in the right place. I Ask it on global furum but didn't get any response.

I have an app that run well on an droid. I want to build it on UWP as well. I have been able to build the app and make it run but some plug-in that use native resource do not work.

For one, native storage,
the second I notice by now is network resource (HTTP request and websocket client).

Those was working well under android. e.i.:

```
getData(): Observable<AlarmData> {
  return this.http.get<AlarmData>(this.server.url() + '/ajax_alarms');
}
```

I have seen that UWP need some certificate, I found in my app at least one related to network:

```
<Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
</Capabilities>
```

But I have not found if and how should I add more...

I tested it on a windows10 machine,
ionic 4.0.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look on MS own sample:

https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/HttpClient

You have to allow the app to use a resource before you have access.

Comment: That's what I thought. But I've not been able to make it work. Also, I cannot find a clear list of capability... for use of native storage or screen orientation for example... I'm very newbie in typeScript and UWP...

Comment: Got it... finnaly find in another forum, I add to add:`<Capabilities>
        <Capability Name="internetClient" />
        <Capability Name="internetClientServer" />
        <Capability Name="privateNetworkClientServer" />
    </Capabilities>` This is on local network, I have to test internet. Also I did not find anyway to unlock native storage...